# What is the difference between AsInteger and Value in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

I want to know the difference between following two statements related to datasets in delphi.

```
dsMyDataSet.ParamByName('ID').AsInteger := 1122; //If ID is integer
dsMyDataSet.ParamByName('ID').AsString := '1122'; //If ID is string
```

and

```
dsMyDataSet.ParamByName('ID').Value := 1122; //ID is string or integer
```

Do these statements carry same meaning? Does "value" implicitly converts integer into string?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `TParam.AsInteger` property, for instance, set the value **and the data type** of the parameter. `TParam.Value` does the same, but `TParam` will decide which type will be mapped to the value inside the `Variant` and not always it´s the data type you would like.

I advise you to set values by using the `AsXXX` properties only, since you will be in control of the parameter's data type, what can save you from having parameter binding errors.

So, answering your final question: no, the values won´t be converted to the right data type, you have to set the data type by selecting the right property to assign the value.

Comment: ok david, what about my doubt:  In my code, at many places dsMyDataSet.ParamByName('ID').Value := 1122; is written. If I Ctrl+Click on value, it takes me to the property "property Value: AnsiString read GetAsAnsiString write SetAsAnsiString;" which is written Data.DB.pas file. This property returns AnsiString. Now if I write a statement like "dsMyDataSet.ParamByName('ID').Value := myString". I will get compiler warning that Implicitly coverted string to ansistring, which may cause data loss. How should I handle this warning?

Comment: @nkp, just typecast to AnsiString to remove the warning. AnsiString('myString').

Comment: @LURD - no I cannot do that, my application is using unicode data. If I typecast to ansistring, I will lose my unicode data. Then whats the use of migrating my delphi 7 application to delphi XE4?

Comment: @nkp: the fact that you can assign 1122 and a string to the Value property proofs that it´s a Variant typed property. Considering that, the warning you said is being issued is very unexpected. Forgive me, but are you absolutely positive on that? Could you recheck the warning and the line of code where it´s happening?

Comment: @nkp, if the data property is declared as AnsiString, the Unicode strings have to be converted at some point. Not sure I follow you.

Comment: @all - At line "dsMyDataSet.Value := myString", I am getting warning: [dcc32 Warning] myFile.pas(319): W1058 Implicit string cast with potential data loss from 'string' to 'AnsiString'

Comment: @nkp Use AsString if you have string data. Also be clear what we are talking about. TParam.Value has type Variant. What are you talking about?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Does it mean that I have to replace all the "value" phrases with "AsString/AsInteger/AsXXX" in my entire application?

Comment: That's what you are supposed to do. It would help if your statements made sense. Value is Variant. So we can't tell for sure what you are doing.