# Delphi FireDAC TFDQuery Parameters - SQL Server Native Client 11.0 - Numeric value out of range

Tags: delphi, firedac

I'm stuck with simple access to a MS SQL Server Table and run into "Numeric value out of range" error msg when trying to open.

The table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ZREZUDET](
    [RZLID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RZLPOSID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ZID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ANTEIL_QUID] [float] NULL,
    [ANTEIL] [float] NULL,
    [KREDID] [int] NULL,
    [ARTNR_SRC] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [RZLID] ASC,
    [RZLPOSID] ASC,
    [ZID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

For opening I use TFDQuery with no special property settings:

```
 FDQparas.Close;
 FDQparas.SQL.Clear;
 FDQparas.SQL.Add('select * from ZREZUDET where RZLID = :P0 and RZLPOSID = :P1');
 FDQparas.Params[0].Value := 1;
 FDQparas.Params[1].Value := -1;
 FDQparas.Open();
```

The automatic parameter creation creates :P0 as ftByte and :P1 as ftShortint whilst the real fields are of type INT.

Coming from ADO/dbGo this worked fine with TADOQuery (ftInteger paras are created).

Is there any setting which helps determination of the correct param-datatypes?

Comment: The automatic typing did a "best guess" and it was wrong for your implementation. You will have to change the parameters' datatypes yourself in the property inspector. Set them to the type (integer) that you know is the correct type for these parameters.

Comment: @nolaspeaker Thx. I hoped to have the same comfort here as it was the case with ADO. As a workaround I iterate thru all given Parameters at time of FDQuery.OnBeforeOpen, check if it is in ftByte,ftSmallint,ftShortint and set ftInteger instead...

Comment: You can specify yourself by doing `FDQparas.Params[0].AsInteger`

Comment: @EirikA. Of course. However, the automatic determination worked fine with ADO but seems to be 'not optimal' in FireDAC and I have hundreds of such Queries. So defining that for each one becomes a heavy task...

Comment: Have a look here.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827503/what-is-the-difference-between-asinteger-and-value-in-delphi/18828170

Comment: @EirikA. Thanks for the link. Changing .Value to .AsInteger/.AsString is not really fun as it is used very often in my app and worked so far with ADO. However, I'll change that step by step...

Answer (score -1):

Rather then `FDQparas.Params[0].Value` you tryed `FDQparas.Params['PARAM_NAME_HERE'].Value`? Futhermore, puting a bracking point in line witch contains the value `-1`, returns a error?

Comment: I tried FDQparas.ParamByName('P0').Value := 1 with the same result. The ErrorMsg rises at time of opening the Query not when I assign the value.